# how to automate the process of opening a file and performing some action in R?

Tags: r, json, automation

I am very new to R and trying to setup some automation. I have some 10-20 json files in a folder, I want to run the R script for each json file so that I can extract data from each json file and keep appending the extracted data in a one dataframe.

In below code `df` is the dataframe that will store data.

In my case I was able to extract data from one json file and stored that data in `df`. How do I do this for all the json file and store the extracted data by appending `df`?

```
json_file <- "path_to_file/file.json"
json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
df <- data.frame(str_split(json_data$data$summary$bullet, pattern = " -  ")) %>% 
  row_to_names(row_number = 1)
```

My output should be a dataframe that contains all the extracted data from each file in a sequence.

I would really appreciate any help.

Comment: what you are looking for is the `list.files()` function to get all the file names in a list and then use either `lapply()` or `sapply()` to read/open them.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might do what the question asks for. Untested, since there are no data.
The JSON processing package is just a guess, there are alternatives on CRAN. Change the call to `library()` at will.

```
library(jsonlite)

read_and_process_json <- function(x, path) {
  json_file <- file.path(path, x)
  json_data <- fromJSON(json_file)
  json_bullet <- stringr::str_split(json_data$data$summary$bullet, pattern = " -  ")
  data.frame(json_bullet) |>
    janitor::row_to_names(row_number = 1)
}

base_path <- "path_to_file"
json_files <- list.files(path = base_path, pattern = "\\.json$")
df_list <- lapply(json_files, read_and_process_json, path = base_path)
df_all <- do.call(rbind, df_list)
```